# TypeError: o.createConnection is not a function

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs

I am trying to connect my node.js app to mysql database. But every time I call the query, I get this error:

> TypeError: o.createConnection is not a function. (In 'o.createConnection(this.config.port,this.config.host)', 'o.createConnection' is undefined)

How can I fix this?

My code:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

const conn = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost', 
  user: 'user_name', 
  password: 'password', 
  database: 'database_name'
});
...
...
const onbClick = () => {
    const sql = "INSERT INTO Orders (field1, field2, field3, field4, field5) VALUES (a, b, c, d, e, f)";
    conn.query(sql, (err, rows) => {
      if(err) throw err;
      console.log("successful");
    });
  }
```

Comment: Missing semi colon `const mysql = require('mysql')` not sure how serious that is in this context

Comment: Have you installed the mysql package properly?

Comment: @C.Champagne yes, `npm install mysql` as the official documentation says

Comment: Where have you added `conn.connect()` method?